# how to change area of contours formation in opencv (threshold)

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, contour

I am trying to build OCR for extracting text from Image, I am using contours in forming boundaries of text characters,

After several trials of changing cv2.threshold i got best fit of contours in forming boundaries of text characters.

```
#files = os.listdir(r'letters/harry.jpeg',0)
file = r'/home/naga/Documents/Naga/Machine Learning/Data_extract/letters/Harry/Harry Potter and the Sorcerer s Stone-page-006.jpg'
im1 = cv2.imread(file,0)
im = cv2.imread(file)

# ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(im1,180,278,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# _,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(im1,180,278,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
dilated = cv2.dilate(im1,kernel,iterations = 1)
_,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    #bound the images
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),1)

cv2.namedWindow('BindingBox', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imwrite('output2/BindingBox4.jpg',im)
```

[image: Contours on text with Opencv]

Now i would like to create contours on words. I need parent contours on each word. what are the attributes to change in Open cv.

I am new to opencv, I followed through [cv2 threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) but could'nt understand to apply it on. plz give your inputs in forming contours on words.

[image: original pic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to dilate the result of the threshold image before you run the findcontour function.

```
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(im1,180,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh1,kernel,iterations = 2)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

A dilation is a morphological function that increases the area of a binary blob. It will tend to combine all nearby blobs to form a singular blob which is exactly what you need to combine the text into words.

You can increase the iteration number if not all your text are combined to a single word. This requires some trial and error if you are uncertain of the value to use here.

Read up on morphological processes to have a better understanding in that topic. It is a useful tool to have for basic image processing.

As an extra tip, try searching for the function adaptivethreshold in openCV. It will make your life easier when binarizing the text image.

Comment: Hi @yapw87 , Thanks for your response. I applied your code on image along with different trials in changing iterations, i couldnt see any variation. i am trying to understand the kernel and dilation in documentation.

Comment: No variations in results? Can you post some examples of the result you have created and the code implementations?

Comment: @yaspws87 i just added code which i have tried with the both thresholds, after implementation of dilation in code, i am not able see any contours in image. If you dont mind, can you try on original image

Comment: ok i have downloaded and tested the code and made some minor changes to my answer earlier. 1) You need to apply the THRESH_BINARY_INV because we want the dark area to be 1 and bright area to be 0. Usually our main area of concern is marked as 1.  2) You need to pass the result of thresholded image to the dilate function for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your time , it is working fine in recognising :-)